# Multiple download with NSURLSession and progressbar animation in UITableview

Tags: download

I've to show list of files in tableview. Each row contains download button.
When i click download button it should show circular progressbar for downloading like the one in the appstore iphone and once the download finished i've to show tick icon on download button. For downloading i'm using NSURLSession with downloadtaskwithurl. It can also download multiple file at same time.

Here i use circular progressbar with UIcontrol. 
    Created customcell for uitableview and added progressbar in tableview.

But circular progressbar not working. Also can't show multiple downloading in UITableview. It shows progressbar without progress in selected cell only. If i select for multiple download the tableview shows progressbar in last clicked cell. Any help

This is the code im using

```
-(void)didload{NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:@"identifier"];
    defaultConfigObject.timeoutIntervalForRequest=10.0;
    defaultConfigObject.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 4;
    NSOperationQueue *myQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [myQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:4];
    NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: self delegateQueue: nil];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:signedUrlStr];
    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask=[defaultSession downloadTaskWithURL:url];
    [downloadTask resume];}


- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask
      didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten
 totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten
totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite {

    CGFloat progMax = (float)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
    CGFloat prog = (float)totalBytesWritten;

    NSLog(@"data length %lu",(unsigned long)totalBytesWritten);
    NSLog(@"Siva %lu",(unsigned long)totalBytesExpectedToWrite);

    cell.progressbar.value=0;
    cell.progressbar.maxValue=progMax;
    cell.progressbar.value=prog;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

        [_tableMonth reloadData];
    });
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task
didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error {
    if (error) {
        // Handle error

        NSDictionary *userInfo = [error userInfo];
        NSError *underlyingError = [userInfo objectForKey:NSUnderlyingErrorKey];
        NSString *underlyingErrorDescription = [underlyingError localizedDescription];
        NSInteger underlyingErrorCode = [underlyingError code];

        NSLog(@"Error desc %@",underlyingErrorDescription);
        NSLog(@"Error code %li",(long)underlyingErrorCode);

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:[Language get:@"retrykey" alter:@"title not found"]
                                                      delegate:self
                                             cancelButtonTitle:[Language get:@"okaykey" alter:@"title not found"]
                                             otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"File download completed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code to update progress bar:

     [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
```